# Best way to export a vector logo from Illustrator to Photoshop for printing?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, vector, logo, print-design

I have a vector logo (eps-file) that needs to be exported to an A4-flyer created in Photoshop for printing (as a PDF).

What is the best way to export the logo to Photoshop at the appropriate size while keeping it nice and crisp?

I tried to export it as a PNG, but if you zoom into the document the logo is not very sharp compared to the text in Photoshop.

I also tried a smart object, which gives better results, but it is still not convincing.

What is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Copy the object(s) in Illustrator and paste to Photoshop as a Smart object.

Comment: So a smart object is the best way to handle this?

Comment: Since you have Photoshop... and you have Illustrator... I'm going to guess you have InDesign. The Flyer quality will be much better if you use it and much smaller file size.

Comment: @Ryan, the flyer is just template, which was created in Photoshop (GraphicRiver). But thanks for the info. So you recommend InDesign for future print jobs?

Comment: @Neo83 yes absolutely. Photoshop for the photo/image manipulation. Illustrator for complex vectors. InDesign for type, simple vectors, and final composition.

Comment: @Ryan, ok thanks. I am wondering why they are selling then printing templates as Photoshop-files. But well can't change it now.

Comment: @Neo83 Because beginners don't know better and they're capitalists. A quick glance at Graphicriver shows that some are INDD files and some are as you've discovered PSD files. I'd look for INDD next time if looking for print.

Comment: @Ryan, I imported the logo now as a smart object and saved the whole file as a PDF in press quality.

Comment: Just place in Photoshop as a smart object. If the Photoshop file is configured for print, the logo will print just fine.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the actual logo it's not possible to give a definitive answer to this, but importing it as a Shape Layer or vector paths would be the best way to do it if it's a simple logo, because your PSD would then contain live vector shapes that would output cleanly to PDF.

When you import a vector logo (or any other vector) as a Smart Object, Photoshop retains the vector information *inside the Smart Object*, but what is presented in the PSD is a raster *representation* of the contents of the S.O. at whatever the resolution is of the PSD. A Smart Object is always a raster interpretation of its contents at the same resolution as the containing document. When the PSD is saved, or output to PDF, it's the raster representation that is output, not the vector information.

Since you're sending this to PDF, your best bet would be to increase the resolution of the PSD to 600 ppi or greater without changing its print dimensions (i.e., turn *on* "Resample image" in the Image Size dialog, then increase the ppi). When you save this as a PDF, the print dimensions will be the same, but you'll get cleaner edges on your logo than you would from a 300 ppi document.

An alternative, better approach would be to place the PSD template into InDesign as a background, *without* the logo or text, then add both text and logo in InDesign. Given that you're stuck with the template you purchased, that might be the better way to go at this point.

Comment: There is no point in exporting to 600ppi.

Answer (score 0):

I would say use a smart object, however you could try doing 'save for web'as a PNG. This gives you more options than the default export, such as image scaling and the type of smoothing applied (none, art or text optimized smoothing). for best quality probably use 'art' smoothing and a large image scaling for best resolution (it should say the pixel dimensions next to these options)

Good luck, let me know if you have any more issues.

Comment: Save for web will create files of **low resolution** and should **never** be used for projects designed for print.

Answer (score 0):

Don't send Photoshop to do a vector or page layout job.

Turn it around. Export the .psd to a .eps and place that in Illustrator, then import the logo (or paste it).

Even better, place the .psd into InDesign, then import the Illustrator .ai logo, then export to a .pdf.

Best — rebuild the layout in InDesign.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question more directly. Indesign is designed for print primarily and is the best option (in my experience) assuming your document has text and a bitmap image in it. Indesign will accept the EPS file from Illustrator and a backdrop bitmap from Photoshop and as WillAdams suggested output as a PDF which the printer will prefer (PDF is designed for pre-press these days).

If you wish to combine your vector with a bitmap image (photo / backdrop) in Photoshop then export the vector from Illustrator as an EPS file (Save as in some versions). Drag this onto the Photoshop application and a dialogue box will appear. Select CMYK and 300 dpi and a suitable size for you end document (210 x 297mm in your case) - this will ensure that the colour space, size and dpi are correct for your project. If you have built your vector well you will not see any broken edges or fuzzyness.  Once you are happy with the design, save the file out of Photoshop as an EPS without compression and import to Indesign. Set additional text on the document layout.

To be clear on some of the other answers (all positive in their own way): - vectors can do lots of things that you don't need in this instance (I wouldn't edit a vector in Photoshop for example so why the Smart Object?. - Illustrator can be used to typeset and produce a print document without Indesign (packaging industry do this as its often simple flat colour, text and icons - no bitmap). However, Indesign is more flexible and has better PDF integration (for pre-press).
- Photoshop can produce a PDF directly at press quality for a printer without Illustrator or Indesign (it's in the Export / PDF / Presets) and I have done this on occasion for (foreign) printers who required a flat image file by FTP but its tedious to layout, will lose sharpness in text (especially under 10 point) and not ideal for DTP.

Hope this helps